# SQL - create a column from two tables - an array int column and string table - matching conversion

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

So I have the following databases, `A` and `B`.  A database contains a table, let's call it `Table1`.  `Table1` has a column named `code` that contains an array of int.

```
Table1

[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
```

In database `B`, there is a table called `Table2` where it has the following columns, `name`, `code`.

So I have a code `1` then I can use `Table2` to find out the name, which is 'first'.

What i would like to do is, find the names based on the code from `Table1`.  So the new column in the select statement will be

```
newColumn

first,second,third
fourth,fifth,sixth
```

Note: w/out the square brackets

Is there any way to do in SQL(Athena)?  I'm trying to unnest the array but i can't get it to create a new column.  Can anyone help? I'm new to sql, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Word of advice. Avoid using `arrays` if you plan to have relationships with them. Put those values in separate rows and establish a FK (foreign key).

Comment: You can UNNEST (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) int array, then join with `Table2` on `code` to get the `name`, then `array_agg` (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#array_agg) to assemble names into an array. Of course, for this you need some unique id in `Table1` so that you can reverse unnesting.